# How to use the develop branch of Zend Framework 2 over composer?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, dependencies, composer-php

In an Apigility driven application my `composer.json` is looking like this:

```
{
    "name": "misc - myproject-api",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for Apigility",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.23",
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">=2.3.2,<3.0.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-documentation": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-development-mode": "~2.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-rest": "~1.0-dev",
        "zf-commons/zfc-base": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.8.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-admin": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-apigility-welcome": "~1.0",
        "zfcampus/zf-deploy": "~1.0",
        "zfr/zfr-cors": "~1.0",
        "zend/zend-studio-development-mode": "~1.0"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "api",
        "apigility",
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "support": {
        "email": "apigility-users@zend.com",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/apigility",
        "source": "https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton",
        "issues": "https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-apigility-skeleton/issues"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.0-dev",
            "dev-develop": "1.1-dev"
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 5000
    },
    "type": "library",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "homepage": "http://apigility.org/"
}
```

There is a ZF2 [issue](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6812) (that causes following error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet as array`). It has been [fixed](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/commit/9f1aeb9eaf3b6f85b3a0f0d9cedfae9364d0dc58), but not merged to the `master` branch yet.

Since I need it working now, I tried to switch to the [`develop`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/develop) branch -- updated my **`composer.json`**

```
{
    "name": "misc - myproject-api",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for Apigility",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.23",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "dev-develop as dev-master"
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and executed a `composer update`:

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Updating zendframework/zendframework (dev-master de98f63 => dev-develop be0b349)
    Checking out be0b3496b73a61a255d05e945b75f6fdf0995c31

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

**Problem**: I'm not observing any changes, the code seems still to be loaded from the ZF2 `master` branch (e.g. my local `Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect` has exactly the state of the according class in the `master` branch).

**How to load the ZF2 `develop` branch?**

---

**UPDATE**

I've triedthe the composer `require` direction value for the `develop` branch (`2.4.*@dev`) from the [Packagist page of the Zend Framework](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zendframework). The result is the same as with `dev-develop` or `dev-develop as dev-master` -- the console shows the correct branch (or better the correct commit `be0b349`) downloading

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing zendframework/zendframework (2.3.4)
  - Installing zendframework/zendframework (dev-develop be0b349)
    Cloning be0b3496b73a61a255d05e945b75f6fdf0995c31

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

but after the updating, the code is still like in the `master` branch.

---

**UPDATE**

```
$ cd [project root directory]/vendor/zendframework/zendframework
$ git status
# On branch develop
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

That means, the branch is correct. And its also up-to-date, since the last commit , `git log` shows is `be0b3496b73a61a255d05e945b75f6fdf0995c31` from 3d of February -- and that is actually the [current HEAD revision](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/commit/be0b3496b73a61a255d05e945b75f6fdf0995c31).

So, the branch is correct, the revision is correct... Why is the code uot-of-date?

Answer (score 0):

The "develop" branch has an alias to be version 2.4. You could require "2.4.*@dev" to get it.

If this breaks some of your dependencies, you could alias this with a 2.3 version.

```
"zendframework/zendframework": "dev-develop as 2.3.4.1"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I tried this out, but the result is the same (see the first UPDATE). Later I noticed, that the branch itself is correct (see the second UPDATE) and only the code is "wrong". I don't understand, why it is so and how it's possible.